# Oracle Delete/Update in one query

Tags: oracle

I want to Delete the Duplicates from the table update the unique identifier and merge it with the already existing record.

I have a table which can contain following records -

```
ID     Name            Req_qty
1001   ABC-02/01+Time   10
1001   ABC-03/01+Time   20
1001   ABC              30 
1002   XYZ              40
1003   DEF-02/01+Time   10
1003   DEF-02/01+Time   20
```

And I am expecting the records after the operation as follows:

```
ID    Name    Req_Qty
1001  ABC      60
1002  XYZ      40
1003  DEF      30
```

Any assistance would be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you will need to update the records first and then delete the records which are not required as following (Update):

```
UPDATE TABLE1 T
SET T.REQ_QTY = (
        SELECT
            SUM(TIN.REQ_QTY) AS REQ_QTY
        FROM
            TABLE1 TIN
        WHERE TIN.ID = T.ID
    )
WHERE (T.ROWID,1) IN 
(SELECT TIN1.ROWID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TIN1.ID) 
FROM TABLE1 TIN1); --TAKING RANDOM RECORD FOR EACH ID

DELETE FROM TABLE1 T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 TIN
WHERE TIN.ID = T.ID AND TIN.REQ_QTY > T.REQ_QTY);

UPDATE TABLE1 SET NAME = regexp_substr(NAME,'[[:alpha:]]+');
```

**--Update--**

The following merge should work for you

```
MERGE INTO 
(select rowid as rid, T.* from MY_TABLE1 T )  MT
USING 
(
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT ID,
regexp_substr(NAME,'^[[:alpha:]]+') AS NAME_UPDATED,
SUM(Req_qty) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS Req_qty_SUM, 
ROWID AS RID
FROM MY_TABLE1) MT1
WHERE RN = 1
) mt1 
ON (MT.ID = MT1.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET MT.NAME = MT1.NAME_UPDATED, MT.Req_qty = MT1.Req_qty_SUM
delete where (MT.RID <> MT1.RID);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. But  the Name string length is not fixed, It can be ABC or ABCD so I want to have everything before the Date Hyphen.(Multiple Hyphen can occur too but still everything before the date hyphen will be picked). 
Also,Name and ID are Primary keys but not the qty, so update will give Constraint Violation.  :(

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: If name and id are primary key then `1003   DEF-02/01` should appear only once. I don't think that they are primary key

Comment: Thanks Tejas. But these also have Time stamp appended so it can be a primary key. Sorry for the confusion, but have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this in a single SQL statement:

```
merge into (select rowid as rid, x.* from test_table x ) o
using ( select id
             , regexp_substr(name, '^[[:alpha:]]+') as name
             , sum(reg_qty) as reg_qty
             , min(rowid) as rid
          from test_table
         group by id
                , regexp_substr(name, '^[[:alpha:]]+')
               ) n
   on (o.id = n.id)
 when matched then 
      update
         set o.name = n.name
           , o.reg_qty = n.reg_qty
      delete where o.rid > n.rid;
```

#### [Working example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4cc5581d1d9b19c7a8810611b05496ed)

This uses a couple of tricks:

- the [`delete` clause of a `merge` statement will only operate on data that has been updated](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9017.htm#i2081030), and so there's no restriction on what gets updated.
- you can't select `rowid` from a "view" and so it's faked as `rid` before updating
- by selecting the minimum `rowid` from per `ID` we make a random choice about which *row* we're going to keep. We can then delete all the rows that have a "greater" rowid. If you have a primary key or any other column you'd prefer to use as a discriminator just substitute that column for `rowid` (and ensure it's indexed if your table has any volume!)

Note that the regular expression differs from the other answer; it uses caret (`^`) to anchor the search for characters to the beginning of the string before looking for all alpha characters thereafter. This isn't required as the default start position for `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` is the first (1-indexed) but it makes it clearer what the intention is.